# Some app keeps turning on mobile data

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, mobile-network

There is some app that turns on mobile data. I turn it off but on sleep or power up it is back on. It is very annoying and potentially costly since I do not have a data plan. (this seems like an intentional way to rip off consumers... off should mean off)

Comment: Do you use some kind ot automation software (Tasker, Llama, JuiceDefender, ...)?

Comment: @Izzy I don't think so. I have a few apps but I installed several. It seems to be staying off now but even the news and weather somehow is getting it's data when I imagine it shouldn't. My guess is that it is not actually disabling the mobile data or some apps are bypassing the setting.

Comment: I Don't know if the "disabling" part comes after the phone loads a few services which get to access the mobile data before the "disable" kicks in. I imagine ATT will rape me over this and I imagine the design was intentional so the raping could be had.

Comment: Check the playstore for an APN switching app (e.g. [APNWidget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tw.edu.ntu.mobile.apnwidget)). Disabling your APN completely makes enabling mobile-data useless, as it cannot find any way to connect. Quick and dirty, but works :)

Comment: Some apps can use data even when it is turned off. For instance, my data does not have to be on to send or receive MMS messages. However, I didn't think many 3rd party apps had this access.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I saw this post and sympathise with the originator. I was using Battery Defender App which worked quite well. However I kept finding mobile data turned on regardless of what I did. This was wasting money for nothing as I just use my wifi at home for internet access etc. I don't need or use this when I am out. I eventually fudged the issue by changing the APN. This worked ok except mobile data was still swithced on all the time doing nothing.
In battery defender the app overrides the phone settings and reactivates mobile data. As far as I can tell there is no way of changing this in the app.
Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 2):

I found out how to disable mobile data for some apps.

Go to **Settings**  →**Mobile data** (you'll see a list of apps that use Mobile data like Skype, Viber, Whatsapp, and so on) → tap one of them (e.g. Viber) → scroll down to **Disable mobile data** or similar → Tap it and agree to what is mentioned there.

Now you disabled Mobile data for Viber. You might be having lots of apps but the effort pays off! You may limit mobile data usage to `0` since it works too. :)

Answer (score 0):

Apps need a special permission to turn on or off mobile data. There's no built-in way to search for apps that use a particular permission, but you can look at the list of apps in **Settings → Apps**.  In the "downloaded" list, if you click on a suspect app, you can see what permissions it uses. The permission you're looking for is "change network connectivity". Any app with that permission might be connecting or disconnecting networks. If you found one in the "downloaded" list, and you don't think it should be allowed to do that, there's a button to uninstall it.

You can also see what permissions each app wants before you install it, in the Play Store's install screen.

Comment: Can I not be able just to disable that permissions on the app?

Comment: I'm afraid not. Permissions are an all-or-nothing thing. The reasoning is that if an app asks for a permission, it must rely on it, so disabling just that permission wouldn't make any sense. I know that's not always true, and I hope Google will consider adding that feature, but for now that's how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a good experimental app that claims to reduce application permissions (including internet)

Its called [Permission Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmail.permissionmanage). Try it and comment on the results.

Also, check your *superuser app log* and look for the app that toggles your internet connection. *Android 2.2 and up* does not allow apps without *root* to toggle your internet connectivity automatically.

Also if you use the official Facebook app, use [Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify&hl=en) to stop it from constantly getting updates and possible turning on your mobile data.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, and in my case it turned out to be Prey (https://preyproject.com/) which was causing this. It was unexpected behavior as it was working fine all this while before.

Answer (score 0):

If you're rooted I'd just use [Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify) and [Notification Toggle](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.j4velin.notificationToggle). Both can be found in the play store and I know notification toggle works, I've used it since it first came out.